# How to merge the dictionary with same key?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

I want to merge the below code with Keys Action and Thriller. Only 2 keys will be present {'Action':[list of movies], 'Thriller':[list of movies]}. New code also welcome like lxml or BeautifulSoup.

## My Code is below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict
tree = ET.parse('movies.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
d = {}
for child in root:
    #print( child.attrib.values())
    for movie in root.findall("./genre/decade/movie[@title]"):
    #print(movie.attrib)
        #print (list(movie.attrib.values())[1])
        d[child.attrib.values()]=list(movie.attrib.values())[1]
d
```

## My output

```
 {dict_values(['Action']): 'Indiana Jones: The raiders of the lost Ark',
 dict_values(['Action']): 'THE KARATE KID',
 dict_values(['Action']): 'Back 2 the Future',
 dict_values(['Action']): 'X-Men',
 dict_values(['Action']): 'Batman Returns',
 dict_values(['Action']): 'Reservoir Dogs',
 dict_values(['Action']): 'ALIEN',
 dict_values(['Action']): "Ferris Bueller's Day Off",
 dict_values(['Action']): 'American Psycho',
 dict_values(['Thriller']): 'Indiana Jones: The raiders of the lost Ark',
 dict_values(['Thriller']): 'THE KARATE KID',
 dict_values(['Thriller']): 'Back 2 the Future',
 dict_values(['Thriller']): 'X-Men',
 dict_values(['Thriller']): 'Batman Returns',
 dict_values(['Thriller']): 'Reservoir Dogs',
 dict_values(['Thriller']): 'ALIEN',
 dict_values(['Thriller']): "Ferris Bueller's Day Off",
 dict_values(['Thriller']): 'American Psycho'}
```

My xml is from datacamp. Data camp is providing information about scrapping
Below is the xml and I have saved in my local folder and named as movies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<collection>
    <genre category="Action">
        <decade years="1980s">
            <movie favorite="True" title="Indiana Jones: The raiders of the lost Ark">
                <format multiple="No">DVD</format>
                <year>1981</year>
                <rating>PG</rating>
                <description>
                'Archaeologist and adventurer Indiana Jones 
                is hired by the U.S. government to find the Ark of the 
                Covenant before the Nazis.'
                </description>
            </movie>
               <movie favorite="True" title="THE KARATE KID">
               <format multiple="Yes">DVD,Online</format>
               <year>1984</year>
               <rating>PG</rating>
               <description>None provided.</description>
            </movie>
            <movie favorite="False" title="Back 2 the Future">
               <format multiple="False">Blu-ray</format>
               <year>1985</year>
               <rating>PG</rating>
               <description>Marty McFly</description>
            </movie>
        </decade>
        <decade years="1990s">
            <movie favorite="False" title="X-Men">
               <format multiple="Yes">dvd, digital</format>
               <year>2000</year>
               <rating>PG-13</rating>
               <description>Two mutants come to a private academy for their kind whose resident superhero team must 
               oppose a terrorist organization with similar powers.</description>
            </movie>
            <movie favorite="True" title="Batman Returns">
               <format multiple="No">VHS</format>
               <year>1992</year>
               <rating>PG13</rating>
               <description>NA.</description>
            </movie>
               <movie favorite="False" title="Reservoir Dogs">
               <format multiple="No">Online</format>
               <year>1992</year>
               <rating>R</rating>
               <description>WhAtEvER I Want!!!?!</description>
            </movie>
        </decade>    
    </genre>
    <genre category="Thriller">
        <decade years="1970s">
            <movie favorite="False" title="ALIEN">
                <format multiple="Yes">DVD</format>
                <year>1979</year>
                <rating>R</rating>
                <description>"""""""""</description>
            </movie>
        </decade>
        <decade years="1980s">
            <movie favorite="True" title="Ferris Bueller's Day Off">
                <format multiple="No">DVD</format>
                <year>1986</year>
                <rating>PG13</rating>
                <description>Funny movie about a funny guy</description>
            </movie>
            <movie favorite="FALSE" title="American Psycho">
                <format multiple="No">blue-ray</format>
                <year>2000</year>
                <rating>Unrated</rating>
        <description>psychopathic Bateman</description>
            </movie>
        </decade>
    </genre>
</collection>
```

Comment: Can you please also post your code in getting the data and your `dict` data structure?

Comment: added the code and out

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! If someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox as it also helps and motivates the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine in getting the data, it's just how you are parsing them. In a dict, `.values()` returns a view of the values, which you can possibly store into a list if you want. In this case, you want the value of the dictionary itself which you can by just selecting by key; `child.attrib['category']`. Once you get that, all you have to do is update your dict. Here we will be using `defaultdict` which when the key is encountered for the first time, returns an empty list so we can append the movie titles.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict

tree = ET.parse('movies.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
d = defaultdict(list)

for child in root:
    for movie in root.findall("./genre/decade/movie[@title]"):
        d[child.attrib['category']].append(movie.attrib['title'])

>>d

defaultdict(list,
            {'Action': ['Indiana Jones: The raiders of the lost Ark',
              'THE KARATE KID',
              'Back 2 the Future',
              'X-Men',
              'Batman Returns',
              'Reservoir Dogs',
              'ALIEN',
              "Ferris Bueller's Day Off",
              'American Psycho'],
             'Thriller': ['Indiana Jones: The raiders of the lost Ark',
              'THE KARATE KID',
              'Back 2 the Future',
              'X-Men',
              'Batman Returns',
              'Reservoir Dogs',
              'ALIEN',
              "Ferris Bueller's Day Off",
              'American Psycho']})
```

If you want to select only say, 'Action', you can just select like a normal dictionary key.

```
d['Action']
```